# Wordpress and LDAP plugin authentication failed

Tags: wordpress, plugins, active-directory, openldap

I'm using WordPress 3.9.1 with OpenLDAP 2.4.31 for my sysadmin course project, running an Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS vbox machine with ip 192.168.1.10. I tried almost every WordPress LDAP plugins and only LDAP LPRM works, but I don't like its mapping roles function, so I'd rather use Active Directory Integration plugin but when I test my configuration I get:

```
AD Integration Logon Test

openLDAP installed

[INFO]   method authenticate() called
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------
         PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
         WP  version: 3.9.1
         ADI version: 1.1.4
         OS Info    : Linux ubuntuserver 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686
         Web Server : apache2handler
         adLDAP ver.: 3.3.2 Extended (201104081456)
         ------------------------------------------
[NOTICE] username: mrossi
[NOTICE] password: **not shown**
[INFO]   Options for adLDAP connection:
         - account_suffix: 
         - base_dn: dc=asgobbin,dc=it
         - domain_controllers: 192.168.1.10
         - ad_port: 389
         - use_tls: 0
         - network timeout: 5
[NOTICE] adLDAP object created.
[INFO]   max_login_attempts: 300
[INFO]   users failed logins: 0
[NOTICE] trying account suffix ""
[ERROR]  Authentication failed
[WARN]   storing failed login for user "mrossi"

Logon failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the account suffix i.e. @yourdomain